# Tensorflow elementwise matrix multiplication (for-loop) error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to calculate matrix multiplication with Tensorflow. 
But it occured errors while numpy usage doesn't make errors. 
(Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV))

**Tensorflow with CPU / GPU : occured the error : Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
With Numpy (Without Tensorflow) : It occurs well**

```
import tensorflow as tf
mport numpy as np

num_doc = 1000 #10000
num_topic = 10
num_user = 20 #8000
cost = 0

#### Tensorflow with CPU ####
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    a_dk = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_doc,num_topic]))
    x_uk = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_user,num_topic]))
    x_dk = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_doc,num_topic]))
    for u in range(num_user):
        print u
        for d in range(num_doc):
            for k in range(num_topic):
                cost = cost + a_dk[d,k] * x_uk[u,k] * x_dk[d,k]

#### Tensorflow with GPU ####
a_dk = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_doc,num_topic]))
x_uk = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_user,num_topic]))
x_dk = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_doc,num_topic]))
for u in range(num_user):
    print u
    for d in range(num_doc):
        for k in range(num_topic):
            cost = cost + a_dk[d,k] * x_uk[u,k] * x_dk[d,k]

#### Numpy ####
a_dk = np.random.randn(num_doc, num_topic)
x_uk = np.random.randn(num_user, num_topic)
x_dk = np.random.randn(num_doc, num_topic)
for u in range(num_user):
    print u
    for d in range(num_doc):
        for k in range(num_topic):
            cost = cost + a_dk[d,k] * x_uk[u,k] * x_dk[d,k]
```

I used i7-4k / 16GB ram / GTX-1070(8GB) 
**And I need a for-loop elementwise matrix multiplication solution with Tensorflow.** 
(Actually, My problem is more complex than above code. So it is hard to makes it vectorization)

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: Please add more details, what exactly do you want? Why have you tagged this as c++, do you want the for loop based solution in c++? If you want help in python, tag it as python.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in what you pasted.  You aren't importing numpy correctly.

for tensorflow you need to create a session.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    ... cpu or gpu code here...
    print(sess.run([cost]))
```

for numpy it as built in element wise multiplication

```
result = np.multiply(A,B)
```

Just use that.  You can also index into A, B when calling it

```
result = np.multiply(A[i,:],B[:,i])
```

Comment: I want to compute it through tensorflow not numpy.

Comment: if you're using version 0.11 and up it's almost the exact same notation as numpy. result = tf.matmul(A,B) or result = tf.matmul(A[i,:],B[:,i])

Comment: I use tensorflow 0.10. And I want to compute above equation #### Tensorflow with GPU #### not just tf.matmul(A,B) or tf.matmul(A[i,:],B[:,i])

Comment: You should be able to vectorize your approach is what I'm suggesting.  It will go much faster than a for loop.

Comment: tmp = tf.matmul(A[i,:,:],B[:,i,:]); res =  tf.matmul(tmp[i,:,:],C[:,:,i]) you should be able to generalize it.

Comment: But the equation that i want to solve is not easy to vectorization (As I said, "(Actually, My problem is more complex than above code. So it is hard to makes it vectorization")

Comment: A and B are 2-tensor (just a matrix). why did you use A[i,:,:] ??

Comment: Added extra dimension by mistake but I disagree that its difficult to vectorize.  a_dk[d,k] * x_uk[u,k] * x_dk[d,k] all share common k "length." Just do  a_dk * x_dk first then multiply by x_uk[u,k] maybe do element wise multiplication of x_uk.

Comment: x_uk[u,k] * cost; cost += a_dk * x_dk

Comment: It is a just simple example. And the real computation that I want is another one. So I said that I need a matrix elementwise computation. The above equation is just a 'simple' equation

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely caused by creating a huge TensorFlow graph, with at least 10 nodes per innermost loop iteration. Operations like this are more efficiently computed using TensorFlow's built-in elementwise operators, which support [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to avoid the need for materializing the whole matrix. For example, your program could be written with two (elementwise) [`tf.multiply()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/multiply) operations and a [`tf.reduce_sum()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_sum):

```
a_dk = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_doc,num_topic]))
x_uk = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_user,num_topic]))
x_dk = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_doc,num_topic]))

ax_dk = tf.multiply(a_dk, x_dk)

# Add extra dimensions to broadcast ax_dk along the user dimension, and
# x_uk along the docs dimension:
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(ax_dk[:, None, :], x_uk[None, :, :]))
```